# How to check database is exist or not?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am using sqlite database in qt. Database created when i use setDatabase("") function. But i dont know how to check same database is exist or not. Here is my code:

```
//add database driver
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase ("QSQLITE");

    //create database
    if(db.databaseName () == db_Name){
        qDebug() << "Database exist or not created." << endl;
    } else {
        db.setDatabaseName (db_Name);
        qDebug() << "Database created." << endl;
    }

    //opening connection
    db.open ();

    //if connection created
    if(db.isOpen ()){
        qDebug() << "Database connected." << endl;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Database not connected." << endl;
    }
```

I get the Database created. message. How to check ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check the database file whether it exists using `QFile`:

```
if (QFile::exists(db_Name)) {
    // database exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite creates an empty database when you try to open a nonexisting file.

So if you want to know if you need to create the tables for your application, just run a query to check whether these tables exist:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'MyTable';
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mere checking for the existence of a file. I'd also check if opening the named database file has succeeded: perhaps it's a corrupt file (one can model that by attempting to open a clearly incompatible file, e.g. a `.jpeg`).